# Remove/Clear cache policy from AWSAppSyncClient in android

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-appsync

I am trying to remove/clear the cache mechanism from AWSAppSyncClient.

Now the problem is i am getting the value which is store or request early (it is cacheing the value and returning that value)

what i want is, it should return the value from the api.(should not cache the value).

i have tried this :

```
AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
            .context(syncPort.androidContext())
            .awsConfiguration(AWSConfiguration(syncPort.androidContext()))
            .build()
            .clearCaches(ClearCacheOptions.builder().clearSubscriptions().build())
```

Query code :

```
override fun getMedication(date: String): Single<SampleAdministration> {
return Single.create<SampleAdministration> { emitter ->
    client.query(
        GetSampleQuery.builder().date(date).build()
    ).enqueue(object : GraphQLCall.Callback<GetSampleQuery.Data>() {
        override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
            emitter.onError(e)
        }

        override fun onResponse(response: Response<GetSampleQuery.Data>) {
            val data = response.data()?.sample
            val sampleAdministration = object : SampleAdministration {
                override var date: String? =
                    data?.date()
            }
            emitter.onSuccess(sampleAdministration)
        }
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

i have remove clearCaches from AWSAppSyncClient.builder()

and added responseFetcher in query

```
 override fun getMedication(date: String): Single<SampleAdministration> {
return Single.create<SampleAdministration> { emitter ->
    client.query(
        GetSampleQuery.builder().date(date).build()
    ).responseFetcher(AppSyncResponseFetchers.NETWORK_ONLY).enqueue(object : GraphQLCall.Callback<GetSampleQuery.Data>() {
        override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
            emitter.onError(e)
        }override fun onResponse(response: Response<GetSampleQuery.Data>) {
            val data = response.data()?.sample
            val sampleAdministration = object : SampleAdministration {
                override var date: String? =
                    data?.date()
            }
            emitter.onSuccess(sampleAdministration)
        }
    })
}
```